# what are the possible answers we can get for the below intergral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Could you please tell me what are the possible answers (if there is more than one) for the following indefinite integral?

$$\int \dfrac{\cos(\sqrt{6x})}{\sqrt{6x}}dx$$

Comment: How could you ever get more than one correct answer for an indefinite integral (aside from the plus-$C$)?

Comment: Yes, I was doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $6x=y^2$. We then have $6dx = 2ydy$. Hence,
$$\int \dfrac{\cos(\sqrt{6x})}{\sqrt{6x}}dx = \int \dfrac{\cos(y)}{y} \dfrac{ydy}3 = \dfrac13 \int \cos(y)dy = \dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{6x})}3 + \text{constant}$$

Comment: But if we take derivative for $\dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{6x})}3 + \text{constant}$  we get 3 times of $\int \dfrac{\cos(\sqrt{6x})}{\sqrt{6x}}dx$

Comment: user, you are forgetting the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

The double appearance of $\sqrt{6x}$ should suggest at least trying the substitution $u=\sqrt{6x}$. (With more experience you’ll know immediately that it’s a good idea, because you’ll be able to look ahead and see that $du$ will the $\sqrt{6x}$ in the denominator that you need.) Now you have $u=(6x)^{1/2}$, so $$du=\frac12(6x)^{-1/2}\cdot6\,dx=\frac3{\sqrt{6x}}dx\;.$$ This is perfect: except for the factor of $3$, it matches the $\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{6x}}$ in your integral, and constant factors are never a problem.

That is, you almost have $\int\cos u\,du$; with a factor of $3$ in the integral you *would* have $\int\cos u\,du$, so write

$$\int\frac{\cos\sqrt{6x}}{\sqrt{6x}}dx=\frac13\int\cos\sqrt{6x}\cdot\frac3{\sqrt{6x}}dx\;,$$

make the substitution, and you have

$$\frac13\int\cos u\,du\;,$$

which readily integrates to $\dfrac13\sin u+C$. Now just reverse the substitution, and you’re home free:

$$\int\frac{\cos\sqrt{6x}}{\sqrt{6x}}dx=\frac13\sin\sqrt{6x}+C\;.$$

Comment: I was trying this again and again, I think I made small mistake there, so couldn't figure out why. But now I am clear. Thank you very much. Every time I solve this, and then take the derivative of that answer didn't give me the same function back. That's why confused. Thank you very much for explaining.

Comment: @user60878: You’re very welcome.